# Removing blue link borders around pictures in HTML emails in Evolution

Tags: evolution

Sorry for the long title.

So I have created an HTML signature file that I want to use in Evolution.  I created it using KompoZer.  I have several images that link to webpages and I made sure in KompoZer and in Firefox that there is no link borders around these images.  When I load the file as my signature file in Evolution it also does not show any link borders, actually it doesn't show the pictures at all, but when I send an email with the signature, the person who gets the email always gets those ugly blue link borders around the graphics.  I have sent test email s to Gmail and Yahoo! Mail accounts and I see it in both of them.  Does anyone know a way I can prevent Evolution from doing this.

Any advice gladly welcome

Comment: Any more or less decent mail client will block links to external images (they are a typical spammer & scammer tool to detect "views").  Evolution will block them (at least, by default).  If GMail & Yahoo! Mail show them, then IMO that only confirms that they are bad mail clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add the border="0" attribute to the img tags. I see that you set the borders to 0px, solid in your style attributes, but perhaps not all html renderers can interpret this (more advanced) css.

<img src="/foo/image.png" border="0" /> accomplishes the same css magic, but only using html which should be more "backward compatible"

Comment: Ah your a genius, it worked, yipee, I can send mail with Evolution now. Thanks a lot. :-D